# Load Denied by X-Frame-Options In Keycloak Docker Instace When Behind A Nginx Proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, keycloak

I have a fairly similar docker-compose file to what is officially provided namely

```
version: '3'

volumes:
mysql_data:
    driver: local

services:
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
        - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
        MYSQL_USER: keycloak
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    environment:
        DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
        DB_ADDR: mysql
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_PASSWORD: mypass
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: mypass
        # It didn't look like this actually got set. 
        PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
    ports:
        - 10000:8080
    depends_on:
        - mysql
```

I also have the nginx config file to be used as a reverse proxy to keycloak

```
## Redirects all HTTP traffic to the HTTPS host
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name keycloak keycloak.fqdn.com keycloak.fq.fqdn.com; 
    server_tokens off;
    return 301 https://keycloak.fqdn.com$request_uri;
}

## HTTPS host
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name keycloak.fqdn.com; 
    server_tokens off; 
    autoindex off;    

    include conf.d/site-common-config/ssl.conf;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/keycloak-access.log combined;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/keycloak-error.log warn;

    location / {
        gzip                    on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000;
    }
}
```

I have furthermore confirmed that (as far as I understand it) the `/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration` is returning the correct values. I have been following the guide [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/server_installation/topics/clustering/load-balancer.html) and have updated the appropiate xml files as well and ran a reload command to ensure that the `proxy-address-forwarding` was set to true. However I get the javascript error

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://keycloak.fqdn.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html?version=4.3.0.final does not permit framing.
```

I haven't been able to find anything in the docs so far to resolve this issue so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If I add the following header in the nginx/openresty config it works:

```
location / {
     …
     add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
     …
}
```

If you want to change the value in the realm with kcadm.sh (as the gui is not working) you can export, edit and import the realm with

```
sudo -u keycloak /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --realm master --user admin --server http://localhost:8080/auth
sudo -u keycloak /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh get realms/master > realm.json
# edit realm.json
sudo -u keycloak /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh update realms/master -f realm.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Configure `X-Frame-Options` in the realm configuration and permit your domain there. Maybe you will need to tweak also `Content-Security-Policy`.

Doc: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#clickjacking

Comment: Just updated the xFrameOptions config value via kcadm.sh to "allow-from https://keycloak.fqdn.com" but it unfortunately didn't work. I'll try tweaking the Content-Security-Policy.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still haven't gotten this to work I have updated the X-Frame-Options value and Content-Security-Policy through kcadm.sh, but it looks like the values don't get updated based upon the fact I still getting the error message. I can't use the GUI either because of this. If you have any more suggestions please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use Keycloak GUI to configure realm settings.

Comment: X-Frame-Options are preventing the it from being rendered. That being said, I added a plugin to ignore the x-frame-options headers in chromium so it render correctly then I updated the defense section so it the headers should be wide open (i.e * l) but I still get a DENY X-Frame-Option header.

Comment: Is it really "*" allowed in the x-frame-options? Please read linked Keycloak doc and RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7034 for proper syntax.

Comment: Ahh dang, yea you're right wildcards aren't supported for X-Frame-Options I'll try setting it explicitly and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, after I changed the X-Frame-Options value to `allow-from https://keycloak.fqdn.com/` still get the same error message.